# Monitor global variable from AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to constantly monitor the value of a global variable from Angular.
I have a flash movie which records microphone data and pushes this out to the global variable.
I reference this variable from Angular like this:

```
$scope.audioData = $window.audioData;
$scope.$watch('audioData', function() {
    console.log("audio in angular!:", $scope.audioData.length);
});
```

and in the HTML I've put:

```
<h1>{{audioData.length}}</h1>
```

In the HTML I can see that the audio data is changed after I recorded, but the watch function is not being called **while** it's recording, which I need to stream the audio to a server.

Comment: watch `audioData.length`, or use the third parameter to [`$watch`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch).

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. The function is still only being called after the recording is stopped (button is clicked).

Comment: you'll probably also want to use [`$apply`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$apply) somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things to keep in mind here.

The first is that `$watch` by default only watches the *identity* of objects and array, so it doesn't notice if there are changes *inside* the value. This can be solved by watching the `length` or using the third argument as  Yoshi has mentioned.

The second thing to remember is that Angular will only check its watches when something triggers it. If nothing is happening in Angular-world, then no watches or callbacks will be executed. Since your recorder lives outside of the Angular-world, it needs to notify Angular that something has been changed. This can be done by calling [`$apply`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply) occasionally after updating the recording. An alternate way to consider is to just have Angular update at regular intervals by using [`$timeout`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout).

Comment: Thanks, this works! Is it also possible to directly call a function on the scope of the controller outside of angular? If I retrieve the scope with angular.element(e).scope(), where e is the top element that gets loaded inside ng-view, I cannot seem to be able to call the functions within the assigned controller.

Comment: @JoostVanDoremalen Not sure, but maybe [`$eval()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$eval) can help you. The proper solution though is to wrap all this stuff in a [directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), but that's a little more work, especially if you're not used to doing it yet.